# Is is possible to run multiple apps in one VM instance?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Do I have to make another VM instance to run another app? Or can I run multiple apps in one instance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Straight forward answer - YES

VMs behave similar to what a regular physical machine would.
In any machine you can run multiple apps , just that they would need to run on different ports.
So, you can run multiple services / applications in a single VM but they would need to run on different ports.

The other things you might have to consider is like the capacity of the VM. Running multiple services in parallel will only lead to more consumption of the RAM and CPU and might lead to exhaustion of the complete capacity.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the VM-instance specs and the expected work-load of each running app on the instance, in case of you are running small-scale apps it will be okay if you decided to do that.

Comment: Maybe giving more details would be helpful? Why and under what circumstances is it ok? When is it not the best idea? SO is a great source of knowledge. Your answer is greatly appreciated and more the details you give, the more knowledge will be transferred :-)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Application performance will depend on your server specifications but you *can* host multiple applications inside a single server.

If you are using apache server, you can refer to this apache documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html